# How to set value of drop down in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 5 and i get the value from action method for drop down and i got these value successfully but i want to set value by default. How can i do this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var markup = "<option value>@Resources.WorkFlowTemplate</option>";
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            markup += "<option value=" + data[x].templateId + ">" + data[x].templateName + "</option>";

        }
        $("#TemplateId").html(markup).show();
    }
});
```

`TemplateId` is the id of drop down list of Html helper.

Comment: What do you mean _set value by default_? What default?

Comment: If you want to set some default value to select drop down you can use **selected** to set value to be selected : `<option selected value=" + data[x].templateId + ">" + data[x].templateName + "</option>`

Comment: plz define what do you mean by default, I have added an answer have a look at it.

Comment: but i want to after show method

Comment: not working. It populate tha drop down but not selected the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a value that you set as default i.e 1 here, and you want to set as selected.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#TemplateId').find('option[value="1"]').attr('selected','selected');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ChiranjeeviIT; you can add `selected` attribute to an option while building dropdown HTML. Also once HTML set, you can preselect dropdown via jQuery as:

```
 $("#TemplateId").val("someValue");
```

where this "someValue" is value of an option of that drop down box as :

```
<option value="someValue">Some Name</option>
```